# Mintty for Cygwin on Windows 10 PC gives me command-line line 0: Unsupported option "gssapiauthentication"

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, cygwin, rsync

I am using a pretty complex rsync script through mintty installed through Cygwin, on a Windows 10 PC and it is giving me the following issue:

command-line line 0: Unsupported option "gssapiauthentication"

The script is using rsync to check if the files have changed, then if it has, it will copy/overwrite it to my NAS.

However, when I run the exact same script on a different but similar Windows 10 PC, it works! I have been troubleshooting this issue for hours on end, to no avail, so have finally come here to see if anybody else smarter than me, may have any tips.

It's very interesting, as on a separate Windows 10 computer, it works fine!!!

Both versions of Cygwin are CYGWIN_NT-10.0 xxxxx 2.11.1(0.329/5/3) 2018-09-05 10:24 x86_64 Cygwin

Both versions of Mintty are 2.9.1

Or maybe they're completely unrelated. I'm out of ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the script again. If possible you can share the script.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue finally... I noticed it was only not working on Windows versions later than version 1803 so I was searching what had changed. Turns out in that update, Microsoft had installed OpenSSH so it was using that version of OpenSSH instead of the cygwin one! Once I renamed the OpenSSH folder to something else in C:\Windows\System32\, re-ran the script, it started using the Cygwin's installed OpenSSH and started working again. Bloody Windows Updates!